# How to create Samsung Galaxy S2 AVD

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, samsung-mobile

How do I create an Android Virtual Disk for the Samsung Galaxy S2?

I have downloaded the skin from [here](http://developer.samsung.com/android/tools-sdks) and followed instructions I found [here](http://www.droidikin.com/create-the-samsung-galaxy-s2-emulator/) but to no avail. I can select Samsung Galaxy S2 as the 'target' in the AVD Manager but the skin is not available from the drop-down list? I have placed the GALAXY_S2 folder in /add-ons/GALAXY_S2 and also /platforms/android-4.2/skins/GALAXY_S2 & /platforms/android-17/skins/GALAXY_S2 but neither seem to work?

Any advice would be much appreciated, feeling a little frustrated here.

Comment: That doesn't work. Also having this problem.